# Как сделать так, чтобы сокет не зависал при чтении тектовых данных?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет

Я разбираюсь с сокетами и столкнулся с проблемой при использовании класса `NetworkStream`.

При бинарной сериализации всё работает.

Клиент:

```
  using (var stream = new NetworkStream(socket))
  {
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(stream, some_request);
  }
```

Сервер:

```
    using (var stream = new NetworkStream(client_socket))
    {
      var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
      DoSomething(bf.Deserialize(stream));
    }
```

Но стоит мне заменить `BinaryFormatter` на `XmlSerializer`, сервер виснет при вызове метода `Deserialize`.

При этом похожая проблема наблюдается при использовании простых текстовых потоков ввода-вывода.

Вот такая конструкция на сервере при чтении строки, переданной от клиента:

```
    using (var stream = new NetworkStream(client_socket))
    {
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
        DoSomething(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

гарантированно виснет. Но можно заставить это работать, если на клиенте в конце передаваемой строки вставить перевод строки, а на сервере читать данные вот так:

```
    while (stream.DataAvailable)
      DoSomething(sr.ReadLine());
```

но, на мой взгляд,  это костыль. Наблюдаемые симптомы указывают на то, что по каким-то причинам у меня в `NetworkStream` вовремя не отрабатывает признак завершения потока, а текстовые потоки ждут его и не могут дождаться. Но как это корректно разрулить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28492779/5045688

Comment: Помогло, спасибо.